# Flexbox sticky footer within scrollable sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a mobile sidebar with a footer that should stick to the bottom, but when there are a lot of navigation links the footer is pushed down and you must scroll to see it.

Here's a simplified demo showing the sidebar already expanded over the content.  You can see the footer sticking to the bottom of the sidebar and not being pushed down with the extra links, and it remains overlapping the links when scrolling.

```css
body {background: #CCC;}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#side-menu-header,
#side-menu-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#side-menu-nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#side-menu-nav a {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside id="side-menu">
  <header id="side-menu-header">
    Logo
  </header>
  <nav id="side-menu-nav">
     <a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a>
  </nav>
  <footer id="side-menu-footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</aside>

<p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p>
```

I've worked with flexbox in the past, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  How can I make the footer appear below the navigation links?

Comment: Hi Chris, do you really need to use `flexbox` in that case, it seems that this could be done without using flexbox at all

Comment: That's probably true... but just seemed (at first) like a good flexbox use case.  I suppose I can try it without.

Comment: @CROSP If to enable the `#side-menu-nav` to fill the remaining space when there is not enough _links_ forcing it to scroll, one need Flexbox to keep the _footer_ at the bottom of its parent (so called "sticky footer").

Comment: @ChrisBarr, yes I got your intention. You already has the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also your `#side-menu-nav` needs to have `flex-shrink: 0;`, or else it will *shrink-to-fit* its parent.

Stack snippet

```css
body {background: #CCC;}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#side-menu-header,
#side-menu-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#side-menu-nav {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#side-menu-nav a {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside id="side-menu">
  <header id="side-menu-header">
    Logo
  </header>
  <nav id="side-menu-nav">
     <a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a>
  </nav>
  <footer id="side-menu-footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</aside>

<p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p>
```

Comment: very interesting.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I clearly read the wrong definition of `sticky`. I thought sticky behaves like `absolute` when the parent is on screen and "sticks" with the parent when the parent is scrolled out of viewport.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu It can be, e.g. when using `position: sticky` ... the so called _"sticky footer"_ though, generally means to either "stick" at the bottom of its parent window, or at the bottom of its parent's content when it overflows and need to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want the Header and Footer of your sidebar sticky. Just give your `#side-menu-nav` a `overflow: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll`, so that the element can fit between header and footer.

```css
body {background: #CCC;}

#side-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

#side-menu-header,
#side-menu-footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#side-menu-nav {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

#side-menu-nav a {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<aside id="side-menu">
  <header id="side-menu-header">
    Logo
  </header>
  <nav id="side-menu-nav">
     <a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a><a href="#">link</a>
  </nav>
  <footer id="side-menu-footer">
    Footer
  </footer>
</aside>

<p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p><p>lots of content here oh yeah so much content!!!</p>
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking, I don't want an internal scrollbar on only the nav, I want the entire sidebar to be scrollable and to have the footer be pushed off the bottom when there are a lot of links

Comment: LGSon was faster.